# Applying root test to sequence $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

The following is an example from Principles of Mathematics, by Rudin. I've been trying to understand the example but haven't quite grasped it because it seems I can solve it differently.

Given the following sequence: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \cdots$

Using the Ratio Test:

$$\lim \inf_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} 
(\frac{2}{3})^n = 0$$

$$\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} 
\frac{1}{2}(\frac{3}{2})^n = +\infty$$

Using the Root Test:

$$\lim \inf_{n \to \infty} (a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{3^n})^{\frac{1}{2n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

$$\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} (a_{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{2^n})^{\frac{1}{2n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

What I don't understand is how to find the $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ for the ratio test. I also don't understand why for the root test, we are looking at the $2n^\text{th}$ root. Where does this 2 come from? Furthermore, are we looking at $a_n$ as alternating between $\frac{1}{2^m}$ and $\frac{1}{3^m}$ or is $a_{n}$ actually $\frac{1}{2^m} + \frac{1}{3^m}$?

As a side note, I do know how to solve this question if asked whether or not this series converges. I simply don't understand the book went around solving it.

Comment: Sequence is ${1 \over 2}, {1 \over 3}, {1 \over 2^2}, {1 \over 3^2}, ...$. So $a_{2m} = {1 \over 3^m}$, $a_{2m-1} = {1 \over 2^m}$.

Comment: @Abstraction Oh, that makes a lot of sense. I feel like I should've noticed that. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you write things like $\frac{1}{2}$ + $\frac{1}{3}$ + $\frac{1}{2^2}$ with "plus" signs and "equals" signs and the like outside of MathJax, instead of $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2^2}$?  (I frequently see people doing that here; I don't know why it's done.  At any rate it's not a proper way to format mathematical notation. $\qquad$

Comment: I don't actually know LaTeX, so I'm doing the best that I can using Google. Most people come here looking for math help so not everyone will be a LaTeX expert.

Answer (score 0):

As Abstraction says, the book uses $n$ for two different things.
$a_n$ alternates between $\frac1{2^m}$ and $\frac1{3^m}$.  So the first, third, fifth... terms are powers of $1/2$, and the second,fourth,sixth... are powers of $1/3$.
For the root test, for example, $\frac1{3^6}$ is the twelfth term, so you look at $\left(\frac1{3^6}\right)^{1/12}=\frac1{\sqrt{3}}$.  For the eleventh term, you should look at $\left(\frac1{2^6}\right)^{1/11}$, but the book looks at $\left(\frac1{2^6}\right)^{1/12}=\frac1{\sqrt2}$.  The true root is $\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)^{12/11}=\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)^{1+\frac1{
11}}$.  This root approaches $\frac1{\sqrt2}$ as you go further in the sequence.
For the ratio test, $\frac{a_{2n}}{a_{2n-1}}$ approaches zero, and $\frac{a_{2n+1}}{a_{2n}}$ grows without limit.

Comment: I suppose what I don't understand is how they got $(\frac{2}{3})^n$ and $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{3}{2})^n$ for the ratio test. But thank you for your answer!

Comment: $(2/3)^n=(1/3)^n/(1/2)^n$, and $\frac12(\frac32)^n=(1/2)^{n+1}/(1/3)^n$